# Is there a simpler way I can check for expected changes in an Angular watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this code:

```
    $scope.$watch('option.sTest', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== undefined && 
            newValue !== null && 
            newValue !== oldValue) {
        }
    });
```

Having this makes my code look bloated. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could implement these checks another way? Note that a value of `0` for newValue or oldValue would be valid so I cannot check like this:

```
    $scope.$watch('option.sTest', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue  && oldValue &&
            newValue !== oldValue) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need them "everywhere" in your code?  Once you have one watch, it listens for any modification to the variable and executes the function if its changed.

Comment: Because I have many select lists "everywhere" and I need to watch for when the user changes the values.

Comment: undefined === undefined and null === null, so you don't need to check both values if you're checking for equality afterwards. I'm not sure why you need this check at all, though.
Edit: Seems you removed those already. At this point, the code is pretty much the same as your other suggestion.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your purpose without some context, but with select lists, another way to track changes could be to bind each select list to separate ng-change functions (or the same one depending on your purpose), which then checks your ng-model(s) scope var (theoretically can't be null || undefined) and processes it accordingly.

Comment: `if (newValue != 0 && newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {}` unless you check empty string value, `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.$watch('option.sTest', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== "undefined" && newValue !== null){

    }
});
```

$watch fires when `newValue` is not equal to `oldValue` so we don't need a check for `newValue !== oldValue`

Answer (score 1):

Personally it wouldn't bother me that much, but you could always write a function if you found yourself using this pattern all over the place.

```
    function isChangedRealValue(newValue, oldValue) {
        return (newValue !== undefined && newValue !== null && newValue !== oldValue)
    }
```

Then in your code:

```
    $scope.$watch('option.sTest', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (isChangedRealValue(newValue, oldValue) {
            // code goes here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to code golf it to a more sparse line, you could do:

```
if (~[undefined,null,oldValue].indexOf(newValue)) {

}
```

I don't see why you need to check for undefined or null though - those shouldn't be cases you need to handle in a watch listener.